# bpy.types.Bone.matrix vs matrix_local

Tags: scripting, bones, transforms, mathematics, matrix

According to the [doc](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Bone.html#bpy.types.Bone.matrix):

> matrix
>
> 3x3 bone matrix
>
> matrix_local
>
> 4x4 bone matrix relative to armature

I guess `matrix_local` is the full transform matrix that describes its location, rotation and scale in Pose Space, right? Then what's `matrix`? Why is it 3x3 instead of 4x4? If it's rotation mode is quaternion, then how 4 numbers fit in the 3-number row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the docs are useless. I'll try to answer based on my understanding from testing.

First, the properties on a bpy.types.Bone aren't affected by the Pose mode pose. Properties affected by the pose are on the bpy.types.PoseBone. So everything in bpy.types.Bone should depends only on the rest pose (the edit mode pose)

`bone.matrix_local` is the transform from bone space to armature space, calculated in the rest pose.

`bone.matrix` is the transform from bone space to its parent bone's space (or armature space if no parent) in the rest pose, but without the translation. The columns are `bone.x_axis`, `bone.y_axis`, `bone.z_axis`, which are the bone's x-axis, y-axis, and z-axis in its parent's coordinate space.

They seem to be related by

```
bone.matrix = (bone.parent.matrix_local.inverted() @ bone.matrix_local).to_3x3()
```

> If it's rotation mode is quaternion, then how 4 numbers fit in the 3-number row?

That's not how it works. In both quaternion and euler mode, the rotation is used to calculate a 3x3 matrix that performs the rotation when applied to a vector. The numbers are never just inserted into a row of the matrix.

Comment: Oh I got it, it's just rotation. I assumed that the 3x3 matrix somehow stores translate+rotation+scale so I got confused.

Comment: But if bpy.types.Bone is bone in edit mode, then what's bpy.types.EditBone...?

Comment: EditBones only exist in Edit mode. AIUI when you leave edit mode, the bpy.type.Bones are all recalculated for the new rest pose.